# Finding the last occurrence of text in a column to result in adjacent cell value

Tags: excel, if-statement, boolean, conditional-operator

This is the current formula that works well when copied down, but now I want the false value to no longer be "", and instead be the value that is 2 columns adjacent to it.

```
=IF(OR(F2="Craps",F2="$$$",F2="PtEst"),"ComeOut","")
```

For instance, when this formula is in cell `G3`, I want it to return the value in `E2`. However, this is not a consistent relative reference.

This needs to be conditional based upon the previous cell being true/false, and want the result to be from the most recent `ComeOut` to take the value in the same row as the most recent `ComeOut` and return the value in column `E` that corresponds with that row of the most recent `ComeOut`.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Here's my spreadsheet:

[image: My spreadsheet]

Comment: Should `G3:G6=6`, `G8:G13=8` (and so on) in your sample screenshot? If not, can you add a screenshot with expected output?

Comment: That is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get expected output please try:

- leave formula in `G2` as it is
- in `G3` enter:

  `=IF(OR(F3="Craps",F3="$$$",F3="PtEst"),"ComeOut",IF(G2="ComeOut",E2,G2))`

and fill it down.

If the the previous value in `G` column is "ComeOut", then take corresponding `E` value. If not - copy previous `G` column value.

Comment: Wow, holy cow! This is perfect, and dont have to utilize a "storing value" column. Such a simple addition; I could have sworn I tried this and was bunk. Thanks again for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way that requires 2 more columns, but you can hide them.

Leave column G as is

Cell H2: =IF(G2="ComeOut",E2,H1) --- Drag this formula down

Cell I2: =IF(G2="ComeOut",G2,H2) --- Drag this formula down

Your desired result will be in column I, but you can rearrange as necessary

Comment: Thanks for the input, this surely works as well. I had a feeling I would need to add another column for storing a holding value.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in a single column. You must enter it as an array formula by hitting Ctrl+Shift+Enter to confirm. In G2:

```
=IF(OR(F2="Craps",F2="$$$",F2="PtEst"),"ComeOut",OFFSET(F2,-MIN(IF(G$1:G1="Comeout",ROW(G2)-ROW(G$1:G1),"")),-1))
```